# Difference between qt and PyQt4

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

Well  I am new to Qt and found its easier to work with python , I dont know how far its true . 
but some of the code snippets have

```
 import qt
```

and some have

```
 import PyQt4
```

I don't know what the difference is, when I tried to interchange them I did get some errors , like some function was not recognizable and so on,  also I am trying to build front end GUI for my application, which GUI framework would u suggest ? Is there anything close to VB like environment ?

Comment: I have PyQt installed and `import qt` (or `Qt`) only gives an ImportError, as expected. A quick look at PySide (another QT binding for Python) shows their package is called `PySide` as expected. Does `import qt` work for you? If so, what's the value of `qt.__file__`?

Comment: well both of them work for me .. that aint the issue . its just that i am unable to understand the difference. how do i check the qt._file_ value ?  PS: i m very new to qt

Comment: The book "Rapid GUI Programming with Python and Qt" only uses the PyQt4 version (usually using `from PyQt4.QtGui import *`). Try doing `imort qt` and then `dir(qt)` or ìmport PyQt4` and `dir(PyQt4)` and compare? or try `help()` instead of `dir()`. Perhaps qt is qt3 and PyQt4 is qt4?

Answer (score 5):

Old PyQt3 use qt

```
import qt
```

Current PyQt4 use PyQt4

```
import PyQt4
```

If you use PySide, use PySide

```
import PySide
```